# If a team played 1 :1 draw with another team and lost in penalty. Another team played 0:0 draw with another team & lost in penalty. Who is best loser

Tags: football

Please, kindly tell me best loser between Team A, who played 1:1 draw with Team B they both went to penalty but team A lost in penalty. Team C, played 0:0 with team D,team C lost in penalty also . So which team is best loser out of team A and Team C?

Comment: It all depends on the tournament rules.